# What is this "the"? What does it mean?

Tags: grammar, definite-articles

> The river is a wonderful sight always.
>
> The rivers are a wonderful sight always.
>
> Rivers are a wonderful sight always.

"The" of "the river" shows the typical image of a river.
But I don't understand "the rivers."
What is this "the?"

Comment: "By the rivers of Babylon ..." always struck me as odd, but it does mean a definite reference to a set of rivers. You may be thinking about the use of 'the' as a designator of a single item to stand for a whole species (eg 'The English gentleman is no longer seen sporting a bowler hat these days.' In this case, 'the' denotes 'English gentlemen, in general'.

Comment: Look up the usage of the definite article the in English.   This is a fairly standard usage, even if it is a bit old fashioned.

Answer (score 3):

"Rivers" means all rivers. "The rivers" means a particular group of rivers.

Answer (score 0):

When you speak of "the river", the word "the" means that you presume the person you're speaking to understands which river you mean.